# Replacing specific characters in string in python

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a file which contains a list of string. Here is the file:

```
['Alabama',
'Auburn (Auburn University)[1]',
'Florence (University of North Alabama)',
'Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]',
'Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]',
'Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]',
'Troy (Troy University)[2]',
'Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]',
'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]',
'Alaska',
'Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]',
'Arizona',
'Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]',
'Tempe (Arizona State University)',
'Tucson (University of Arizona)',
'Arkansas',
'Arkadelphia (Henderson State University, Ouachita Baptist University)[2]',
'Conway (Central Baptist College, Hendrix College, University of Central
 Arkansas)[2]']
```

*I need to make a list which contains the list having string values as:*

```
 ['Alabama',
 'Auburn',
 'Florence',
 'Jacksonville',
 'Livingston',
 'Montevallo',
 'Troy',
 'Tuscaloosa',
 'Tuskegee',
 'Alaska',
 'Fairbanks',
 'Arizona',
 'Flagstaff',
 'Tempe',
 'Tucson',
 'Arkansas',
 'Arkadelphia',
 'Conway']
```

Pleas suggest me any way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are the text shown in your example the exact text in the file, or is it how it looks after you have read it into a list in Python?

Comment: I suggest you write some code.

Comment: `[i.split(' (')[0] for i in my_list]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (replace `data.txt` with your file path):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as data_file:
    data = data_file.read()
    raw_elements = data.replace('\n', '').strip('[]').split(',')
    elements = map((lambda item: item.strip("'").split(' ')[0]), raw_elements)
    print elements
```

Basically it reads the whole file, eliminates the new lines, removes the square brackets from the beginning and the end, splits the content with commmas, removes the `'` from each string, splits again each element using white-spaces and takes the first part.

Answer (score 0):

- In Python there is a **map** function and it is used to apply a *function* to every element in an array
- You can define your function to get what you want from the string, maybe truncate the string in the first space " "! You need to try different things...

Answer (score 0):

I would just write something like

```
map(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0], a)
```

it would always return a list containing the first word of every element of your list.